# RCP4 add banner to window

Tags: java, rcp

Apparently it is possible to add a banner in RCP 3 (Shown in the link below)

https://wiki.eclipse.org/Rich_Client_Platform/Custom_Look_and_Feel

Does anyone know how to do it in RCP 4?  I have gotten as far as subclassing the WBWRenderer, but I don't know which methods to override and how to dynamically 'insert' a banner (aka SWT label) above the menu bar.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even in `WBWRenderer` I think you will struggle to get anything above the menu. The code calls `Shell.setMenuBar` to set the menu, this has a lot of platform specific code for the menu.

You are going to have to study (and probably duplicate) a lot of the source of `WBWRenderer` - look at the `createWidget` method initially.

If you don't already have the Eclipse source installed you can get it by installing the 'Eclipse SDK' from the http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/updates/4.4 site. Once you have it installed open 'Preferences > Plug-in Development' and check 'Include all plug-ins from target in Java search'. Once you have done that you can open Eclipse source using 'Open Type' and the other normal Eclipse mechanisms.